# Click on a text to open an image

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I am very new to this.

How do I click a text and get it to open up an image which is saved in the app?

This is what I have so far, but I am having errors, I am using Fragments and I do not know if I am doing it the right way.

Thanks!

This is what I have now in Fragment_6.java :

```
package com.rufflez.swipeytabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Fragment_6 extends SherlockFragment{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_6, container, false);


TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
String url = "http://androidcookbook.com/seam/resource/graphicImage/escapedn.png";             
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
}
}); 
}

}
```

in fragment_6.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="@string/procedures1"
    />
```

Comment: You have written the logic after the return statement, so rest of the code is unreachable, write "return" line at the end of the onCreateView() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_6, container, false);
// inflate the layout

TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
// initialize textview using inflated view object 
tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
String url = "http://androidcookbook.com/seam/resource/graphicImage/escapedn.png";             
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
}
}); 
reuturn v; // return view
}
```

Comment: thanks! i tried using this and it seems to work. do you know how do i open an image from drawable instead?